# CSS selector for class descendant within a class

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a CSS selector for 'element with class b, which is a descendant of an element with class a'?

Thanks,
Rasto

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible:

Direct Descendants:

```
.a > .b { /* ... */ }
```

All Descendants:

```
.a .b { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the mark-up:

```
<div class="elementClassA">
    <div class="elementClassB">first B element</div>
</div>
<div class="elementClassA">
    <div class="elementClassC">first C element
        <div class="elementClassB">Second B element</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Yeah, for *all* descendants:

```
.elementClassA .elementClassB {
}
```

The above will target both the `first B element` and the `Second B element`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hVjEG/).

For immediate descendants:

```
.elementClassA > .elementClassB {
}
```

This will target *only* the `first B element`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hVjEG/1/).

References:

- [`CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Answer (score 0):

For sure, it's a simple CSS selector:

```
.classA .classB {}
```