# How do I select all "sub" elements inside "main" elements

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="main">
    <p>I don't want this</p>
    <div class="sub">I want this</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <p>I don't want this</p>
    <div class="sub">I want this</div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how to select all "sub" elements inside "main" elements.
I've tried 
    `document.getElementsByClassName("main").getElementsByClassName("sub")`
But that doesn't work. To clarify I want to get all "sub" elements inside "main" classes but can't quite figure out how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("main") returns array of elements, so you need to loop on each one and run getElementsByClassName("sub")

Comment: See [CSS selector for class descendant within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11475553/1529630) and [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/1529630)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a CSS selector with `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```
var subs = document.querySelectorAll('.main .sub');
```

However your posted HTML doesn't place the `.sub` elements inside the `.main` elements; they're siblings; in which case:

```
var subs = document.querySelectorAll('.main + .sub');
```

Or:

```
var subs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll try this out tomorrow

Comment: I've tyres using this method but it also returns divs that have a class of "sub 1" or "sub 2" is it possible to only select divs that have a class of "sub"

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("main")` is a HTMLCollection (a kind of list of elements), so you'd need to iterate over each item in this list and call `.getElementsByClassName("sub")` on each of the elements and concatenate all resulting lists.

But there is a simpler way. Today's browsers support `document.querySelectorAll`, so you can use

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.main .sub');
```

Also none of the `.sub` elements in your sample code is nested inside `.main`. So, the result of the above would anyway be empty.

Comment: Not relevant, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I corrected my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in your example you have no child classes in your HTML. Your HTML should look like this instead:

```
<div class="main">I don't want this
    <div class="sub">I want this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx for the note I'm writing on my iPad so it's not so easy to write HTML code with out mistake

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("sub")` will be enough to select the `.sub` elements in your example.

Comment: But it will get `.sub` elements outside `.main` too.

Comment: Oriol's right I'm looking to just get .sub that are inside .main but thanks for taking the time to answer

Comment: That's what I wrote: "in your example" (I took it you want a solution for that particular situation)